# Android ListView arraylist group items of different positions by comparing with second arraylist

Tags: android-listview, arraylist

I am displaying weekly data in the ListView. I get current week dates using java Calendar class. I am getting data which i have to display into the list inside ArrayList with custom Objects.

Bean Class :

```
    public class SampleBean{

        String date;
        String day;
        String city;
    ............................
    // GETTERS AND SETTERS
    }
```

That array with details contains only seven dates, but one date can be at multiple positions. E.g a date 21 Oct 2014 is at positions 3,4 and 5.

Since i need to show only a weekly view, i have to group the items at the positions with same date and display them in a single row of listview as - " City1, City2, City3" - separated by coma. I want to achieve this by comparing my arraylist with dates from calendar to the custom ArrayList with data to display in ListView

My ListView needs only be the size of 7. Array items with same dates need to be grouped together. For that, i am unable to grind out the logic. My looping patterns have been buggy altogether.

If anyone could give me an idea, sample, or a link about how to go on to achieve this grouping would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I achieved the solution for this using using the count of recurrences of the specific date and then using that count to iterate though the loop to combine the items.